# Does this board cover questions on airport and airline operations?

Tags: discussion, scope

As far as I can tell, this board definitely covers the 'aeroplane side' of aviation (that is the parts directly related to planes).

How about the operations and perhaps more 'commercial' side of airline and airport operations. To me these questions seem very much intrinsic to most people's experience of aviation as they interact with it, even if not from the pilot/mechanic perspective.

As a broad area, I am thinking about how airlines/airports interact with IATA standards (like some aspect of IATCI, or IATA Telex messages).

Alternately, questions like are there standards for airlines to communicate operational information to airports (such as timing changes)?

I am not looking to bring up questions about *specific* airline practices, or particular products. However, as air travel is an area with a large amount of international standardisation, I think there are a lot of questions that can be raised that can be answered objectively and generally.

What do people think?

Answer (score 8):

For the most part, I think that yes, airline-related questions ought to be welcome here. A lot of them seem likely to be regulation-based anyway, which is half of aviation! :)

Whatever you've got, ask away. That's the only way we will know for sure!

There's naturally going to be some overlap with Travel.SE, but that's something we just roll with, I figure.