# Define if airport operations and regulations are on topic in help

Tags: discussion, support, scope, off-topic

As the title says, the aviation help doesn't define if airport operations and regulations are on or off topic.

I personally think they are on if they relate to the aircraft side of operations etc but not passenger side, as per all aviation questions and as described in the help centre.

Either way, can this be clarified and added to the help text?

For reference:

[Question on airport operations that was closed as off topic](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/30465/15982)

[Meta question saying airport operations on topic](https://aviation.meta.stackexchange.com/q/336)

[Meta question saying airport history is on topic](https://aviation.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1567)

Answer (score 3):

I believe this is already fairly well-defined -- "Questions about airport operations" is intentionally broad, but at the same time it should not be construed so broadly as to mean "Questions about anything I saw at, on, or near an airport" -- It's mainly intended to cover things like:

- Questions about ARFF procedures
- Questions about runway/taxiway maintenance
- Questions about airport tugs & such used for moving aircraft

It may also include questions about duty-specific clothing (e.g. the silver fire suits worn by ARFF personnel), but those are at best peripheral to the category of "Airport operations", and if they're closed as off-topic it shouldn't break anyone's heart.

---

In the particular case of [the instant question](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/30465/15982) there are plenty of potentially-on-topic questions about "Why is this person wearing a face shield?" -- mechanics working in a wheel well may be wearing them so falling dirt/hydraulic oil doesn't get in their eyes for instance.

The question we're discussing here doesn't pass muster in my opinion though: We could well be asking why the Brinks driver is wearing a tactical helmet, so I would say this is a case of "Just because it's AT an airport doesn't mean it's RELATED to the airport." and properly closed as off-topic.